# Where-Object in Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I have site collections list

- http://rany1
- http://Rany1/xxx

I want to check if http://Rany1/xxx is exist using where-object instead of foreach if in power shell.

I tried `Get-SPsite | where {$_Url -eq "http://Rany1/xxx"}` it's not working

Help me please!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is small mistake in your code. there should be a "." after '$_".
try this

```
Get-SPsite | where {$_.Url -eq "http://Rany1/xxx"}
```

Answer (score 8):

And just to add to the list of options, you can also replace `Where-Object` and `where` with a little question mark `?`.

```
Get-SPsite | ?{$_.Url -eq "http://Rany1/xxx"}
```

Reference: [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

Comment: excellent new idea

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-PNPSite | where-Object {$_["Url"] -eq "http://rany1/xxx"}
```

Comment: To use Get-PnPSite, you need to use the PnP-PowerShell which you can download from Github https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/GetPnPSite.md

Comment: excellent PNP solution

Comment: that's right, I forgot to mention

Answer (score 2):

Small correction in your syntax.

```
Get-SPSite | Where-Object {$_.Url -eq "<<site url>>"}
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: excellent repeated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The below format also we can use

Get-PNPSite | where-Object {$_["Name"] -eq "Site name"}